# Resolve issues with DNSBLOG and b.barracudacentral.org

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, postscreen

I am using postfix with DNSBLOG to prevent spam. The postfix *main.cf* is configured like:

```
postscreen_dnsbl_sites =
zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[2..11]*3
b.barracudacentral.org=127.0.0.2*2
```

DNSBLOG is preconfigured with zen.spamhaus.org which works great and b.barracudacentral.org which gives me some errors.

```
sudo tail -1000 /var/log/syslog | grep barracuda

Feb 18 21:02:34 my_server postfix/dnsblog[1831262]: warning: dnsblog_query: lookup error for DNS query xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.b.barracudacentral.org: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.b.barracudacentral.org type=A: Host not found, try again
Feb 20 16:11:59 my_server postfix/dnsblog[1930512]: warning: dnsblog_query: lookup error for DNS query xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.b.barracudacentral.org: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.b.barracudacentral.org type=A: Host not found, try again
Feb 21 06:03:10 my_server postfix/dnsblog[1958310]: warning: dnsblog_query: lookup error for DNS query xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.b.barracudacentral.org: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.b.barracudacentral.org type=A: Host not found, try again
Feb 21 14:04:50 my_server postfix/postscreen[1974685]: warning: dnsblog reply timeout 10s for b.barracudacentral.org
Feb 21 14:04:51 my_server postfix/dnsblog[1974686]: warning: dnsblog_query: lookup error for DNS query xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.b.barracudacentral.org: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.b.barracudacentral.org type=A: Host not found, try again
Feb 21 17:03:23 my_server postfix/postscreen[1981146]: warning: dnsblog reply timeout 10s for b.barracudacentral.org
Feb 21 17:03:25 my_server postfix/dnsblog[1981147]: warning: dnsblog_query: lookup error for DNS query xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.b.barracudacentral.org: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.b.barracudacentral.org type=A: Host not found, try again
Feb 22 13:46:04 my_server postfix/dnsblog[2024748]: addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx listed by domain b.barracudacentral.org as 127.0.0.2
```

I replaced real IPs with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

It seems that the DNS can't resolve b.barracudacentral.org. When I do

```
nslookup b.barracudacentral.org
Server:     212.227.123.16
Address:    212.227.123.16#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find b.barracudacentral.org: No answer

nslookup b.barracudacentral.org 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find b.barracudacentral.org: No answer

 nslookup b.barracudacentral.org 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find b.barracudacentral.org: No answer
```

With different servers/hosts in different networks I get the same results. How Can I solve this resolve issue?

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't seem this b.barracudacentral.org is a valid name on barracudacentral.org. At least as of now it's not resolvable.

Comment: Hm... https://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-details.php?dnsbl=b.barracudacentral.org a lot of pages the that b.barracudacentral is actually the correct url for the blacklist...